# Can't display a UTF-8 character on an iOS device

Tags: ios, encoding, utf-8, fonts

I want to display the ⟨ UTF-8 character (aka \u27E8 in the [Unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)) in a UIButton and have a terrible time trying.

I've tried the following options but none worked and I end up getting an ugly square on my device.

```
[myButton setTitle:@"⟨" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"\u27E8" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I couldn't get more successful with a UIWebView:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body>Coucou ⟨ &#10216;</body></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

I made sure my source code was encoded in UTF-8.

Any idea on how I should try to do this? Is it the embedded fonts that miss the character?

Comment: Does your font (or group of fonts) support this character?

Comment: The font is supposed to be Helvetica. Helvetica on desktop does something with it. But that's pretty much my question: is iOS Helvetica missing characters compared to desktop Helvetica?

Comment: and: where can we get documentation on supported characters in iOS.

Comment: You could maybe try to visit this very page on an iOS device, it contains the ⟨ character, so you'll be able to check if it is at least supported by the font used by Safari.

Comment: good point! as a matter of fact, it's not working either! i'll try to embed a font that I know has the character in my app and see if it changes something.

Comment: The font [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) contains a glyph for this character

Comment: The Helvetica font doesn't actually include this character. What you are seeing when you say "Helvetica on desktop does something with it" is the result of the system performing font substitution, where the system detects that the requested font doesn't contain the requested character and substitutes the character from another font instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we implemented here was creating our own font.

We picked basic fonts A (the one with the basic characters we want) & B (including the special characters A is missing) with licenses allowing to mix them to create a third font C and cherry-picked the needed characters from B to A via the [TypeTool software](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/typetool/).